# Testing URL (regex) validation with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, testing, rspec

A Rails 4.2 application has several models with attributes containing URLs. URL validation is done at the model with `validates :website_url, format: { with: /\A(https?|ftp):\/\/(-\.)?([^\s\/?\.#-]+\.?)+(\/[^\s]*)?\z/i }`.

I need to test the URL validation with RSpec 3.5. It is important to ensure that some well-known XSS patterns do not pass validation and that the most commonly used URL patterns pass validation.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid adding one test for each valid and invalid URL I'm testing so the `rspec -fd` output is not polluted. However, that would probably require creating two tests (one for valid URLs and other for invalid URLs) and adding multiple expectations to each test (one expectation per URL), which does not seem like good idea.

The best solution I've come up with so far are the following shared examples. **Can you think of a better way to test URL validation thoroughly?**

```
RSpec.shared_examples "url validation" do |attribute|
  INVALID_URLS = [
      "invalidurl",
      "inval.lid/urlexample",
      "javascript:dangerousJs()//http://www.validurl.com",
      # Literal array is required for \n to be parsed
      "http://www.validurl.com\n<script>dangerousJs();</script>"
  ]

  VALID_URLS = [
      "http://validurl.com",
      "https://validurl.com/blah_blah"
  ]

  context "with invalid URLs in #{attribute}" do
    INVALID_URLS.each do |url|
      it "is invalid with #{url}" do
        object = FactoryGirl.build(factory_name(subject), attribute => url)
        object.valid?
        expect(object.errors[attribute]).to include("is invalid")
      end
    end
  end

  context "with valid URLs in #{attribute}" do
    VALID_URLS.each do |url|
      it "is valid with #{url}" do
        object = FactoryGirl.build(factory_name(subject), attribute => url)
        expect(object).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end
```

Within the model specs:

```
include_examples "url validation", :website_url
```

**Edit**: Added `context` for valid and invalid URLs so `rspec -fd` output is better organized, even with a large number of URL validation tests executed in random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution isn't bad. It makes sense to me to continue to break it down with more `shared_examples`:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "an invalid URL for attribute" do |url, attribute|
  let(:object) { FactoryGirl.build(factory_name(subject), attribute => url) }
  before(:each) { object.valid? }
  specify { expect(object.errors[attribute]).to include("is invalid") }
end

RSpec.shared_examples "a valid URL for attribute" do |url, attribute|
  let(:object) { FactoryGirl.build(factory_name(subject), attribute => url) }
  specify { expect(object).to be_valid }
end

RSpec.shared_examples "URL validation" do |attribute|
  [ "invalidurl",
    "inval.lid/urlexample",
    # ...
  ].each do |url|
    it_behaves_like "a valid URL for attribute", url, attribute
  end

  [ "http://validurl.com",
    "https://validurl.com/blah_blah"
  ].each do |url|
    it_behaves_like "an invalid URL for attribute", url, attribute
  end
end
```

The repeated `let(:object)` bugs me, but I don't have an immediate solution for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have also tried and was unable to avoid repeating the object creation. Even within the same `shared_examples` block, passing the URL from within the loop to the `let` block was troublesome.

Comment: @BrunoFacca Just to clarify, does the above solution work for your use case? Let me know if you're having any issues.

Comment: It works. However, could you please explain the benefits of breaking it down in this way (creating 3 shared examples)? It seems to me that although this approach is clever/sophisticated, it introduces additional complexity without reducing repetition or LOC. Given your experience, I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @BrunoFacca You're right that there isn't a *huge* difference here. I like this approach because the parameterized example groups are more declarative. It seems like these tests are part of a larger suite that's designed in such a way that's forced your hand a bit (ergo `object` instead of `subject`). You might want to post a larger section of your code at [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and see if they have any tips.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will do that.